# Media query changing itself?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I set a media query to change properties of my #secondary wrapper

This is the media query I set

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.left-sidebar #secondary {
    float: right;
    width: 100%!important;
}
```

The problem is its not applying those changes until 479px even though i set it to 676px;

When i look in dev tools in google to view the css it looks like this

```
@media (max-width: 479px)
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
.left-sidebar #secondary {
    float: right;
    width: 100%!important;
}
```

Why could this be happening and how do i fix it?

Comment: Without actually seeing the site / full code, it's impossible to say. But it doesn't happen by itself. Either you have a line or two in the CSS that shouldn't be there, or you have some javascript or other code butting in.

Comment: Please provide the site link.

Comment: the site is locked down because we are in maintenance mode. Can i have ur ip? lol

Comment: Given that both of your provided code blocks are missing braces, my best guess is that you are missing a closing brace on an earlier media query.

Comment: @Gerrit0 That is true and i fixed it and it didnt solve the issue. I believe it didnt matter since it was the last piece of code at the very bottom of the style sheet which most browsers auto close off (I think)

Comment: @Gerrit0 You were right. I donno what I was thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your issue is missing braces on your media queries. I usually find it helpful to indent everything within a media query so this doesn't happen by accident.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .left-sidebar #secondary {
        float: right;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .left-sidebar #secondary {
        float: right;
        width: 100%!important;
    }
```